# R scraping entire html, not just page view

Tags: html, r, xpath, web-scraping

Bit of a difficult question to put into one sentence, but I am trying to scrape some html from the following page

```
http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/snp/?term=(human[Organism])+AND+GLRA3[Gene Name]
```

where I can scrape what I need using R, but because the browser only displays the first 20 entries, only the corresponding html is available to me. This causes a problem, because I want to scrape **all** entries, not just the entries that are being served up by the page on the browser. Any way, here is my R code

```
library(XML)
library(httr)

#Go to Nectar Mutation and get SNP refs
dbsnp.searchterm="(human[Organism])+AND+GLRA1[Gene Name]"
dbsnp.url=paste0("http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/snp/?term=",dbsnp.searchterm)
dbsnp.get=GET(dbsnp.url)
dbsnp.content=content(dbsnp.get, as="text")
links<-xpathSApply(htmlParse(dbsnp.content), "//a[contains(@href, 'snp_ref')]",xmlGetAttr,"href")
```

and result

```
> links
 [1] "/projects/SNP/snp_ref.cgi?rs=116474260"
 [2] "/projects/SNP/snp_ref.cgi?rs=121918408"
 [3] "/projects/SNP/snp_ref.cgi?rs=121918409"
 [4] "/projects/SNP/snp_ref.cgi?rs=121918410"
 [5] "/projects/SNP/snp_ref.cgi?rs=121918411"
 [6] "/projects/SNP/snp_ref.cgi?rs=121918412"
 [7] "/projects/SNP/snp_ref.cgi?rs=121918413"
 [8] "/projects/SNP/snp_ref.cgi?rs=121918414"
 [9] "/projects/SNP/snp_ref.cgi?rs=121918415"
[10] "/projects/SNP/snp_ref.cgi?rs=121918416"
[11] "/projects/SNP/snp_ref.cgi?rs=121918417"
[12] "/projects/SNP/snp_ref.cgi?rs=121918418"
[13] "/projects/SNP/snp_ref.cgi?rs=267600494"
[14] "/projects/SNP/snp_ref.cgi?rs=267606848"
[15] "/projects/SNP/snp_ref.cgi?rs=281864912"
[16] "/projects/SNP/snp_ref.cgi?rs=281864913"
[17] "/projects/SNP/snp_ref.cgi?rs=281864914"
[18] "/projects/SNP/snp_ref.cgi?rs=281864915"
[19] "/projects/SNP/snp_ref.cgi?rs=281864916"
[20] "/projects/SNP/snp_ref.cgi?rs=281864917"
```

You will note that there are 4058 entries that I require.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It took me the entire afternoon and I only still have halve of the solution (first time working with XML whatsoever). Anyway I figured out that you can use the following link to get to the results in XML format;

```
http://eutils.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/entrez/eutils/esearch.fcgi?db=SNP&term=(human[Organism])+AND+GLRA3[Gene+Name]
```

Where `db` stands for the database you want to search in, and `term` is fairly self-explanatory.

On top of the results you will then see;

```
<Count>4736</Count>
<RetMax>20</RetMax>
```

And under this the ID-list starts and shows 20 ID's which are equivalent to the `rs` value in;

`/projects/SNP/snp_ref.cgi?rs=`**116474260**

You can use the `GET` function to get this information in R. Now if you can figure out a way to let R read the number that in on the `Count` row (which is the amount of results that are possible), and then use the `GET` function again but now with `&RetMax=X` added to the end of the link, where X is the number in `Count` row.

For example;

```
http://eutils.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/entrez/eutils/esearch.fcgi?db=SNP&term=(human[Organism])+AND+GLRA3[Gene+Name]&RetMax=4736
```

Now all the ID's are imported in R (again I lack the skills to extract them nicely from the data, so that might be for someone else to figure out).

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

You will want to use the api that @Roost found. I will add that httr has a built-in method for adding query parameters, and you should use it because it will automatically URL encode your query parameters for you.

In XML, using `xmlToList` will be easier if you are not as comfortable with xPath, but you can pick your way to parse the XML.

```
library(XML)
library(httr)

# Go to api and get Count
dbsnp.searchterm <- "(human[Organism]) AND GLRA3[Gene Name]"
dbsnp.url <- "http://eutils.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/entrez/eutils/esearch.fcgi"
dbsnp.get <- GET(dbsnp.url, query=list(db="SNP", term=dbsnp.searchterm))
dbsnp.content <- content(dbsnp.get, as="text")
dbsnp.xml <- xmlParse(dbsnp.content)

max_count <- xmlToList(dbsnp.xml)$Count

# Use the Count to form the query that you want
dbsnp.full.get <- GET(dbsnp.url, query=list(
    db="SNP", 
    term=dbsnp.searchterm, 
    RetMax=max_count))
dbsnp.full.content <- content(dbsnp.full.get, as="text")
dbsnp.full.xml <- xmlParse(dbsnp.full.content)
dbsnp.full.list <- xmlToList(dbsnp.full.xml)

prefix <- "/projects/SNP/snp_ref.cgi?rs="

dbsnp.links <- paste0(prefix, unlist(dbsnp.full.list$IdList))
```

Comment: Hi Waternova - this is a similar approach I would take. I'm quite comfortable using xpath queries which is why the xpathSAPpply() function does the trick for me. But this looks like it would work too.